# Finding Transfer Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Now the goal is to get a polynomial on the numerator and polynomial in the denominator 
I know that we shall multiply it by Cs , I did that. 
But I am not getting the same answer as the textbook’s. it will get very messy and long polynomial in the denominator. Is there any way I can use some shortcuts? to reduce the algebra ?
Here is the final form of the transfer function

[image]

So my question is how to get equation (2) from equation (1) ? 
Thank you

Comment: expand the denominator, simplify the $s^2$ terms, multiply by $C s$. and to find the inverse Laplace transform of more complicated transfer functions you will have to learn the [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\text{I}_2(s)}{\text{V}(s)}=\frac{Ls}{\left(R_1+Ls\right)\left(R_2+Ls+\frac{1}{Cs}\right)-L^2s^2}=$$
$$\frac{Ls}{\left(R_1+Ls\right)\left(\frac{R_2Cs}{Cs}+\frac{CsLs}{Cs}+\frac{1}{Cs}\right)-L^2s^2}=$$
$$\frac{Ls}{\left(R_1+Ls\right)\left(\frac{R_2Cs+CsLs+1}{Cs}\right)-L^2s^2}=$$
$$\frac{Ls}{\left(R_1+Ls\right)\left(\frac{R_2Cs+CLs^2+1}{Cs}\right)-L^2s^2}=$$
$$\frac{Ls}{\frac{\left(R_1+Ls\right)\left(R_2Cs+CLs^2+1\right)}{Cs}-L^2s^2}=$$
$$\frac{Ls}{\frac{\left(R_1+Ls\right)\left(R_2Cs+CLs^2+1\right)}{Cs}-\frac{CsL^2s^2}{Cs}}=$$
$$\frac{Ls}{\frac{\left(R_1+Ls\right)\left(R_2Cs+CLs^2+1\right)-CL^2s^3}{Cs}}=$$
$$\frac{CLs^2}{\left(R_1+Ls\right)\left(R_2Cs+CLs^2+1\right)-CL^2s^3}=$$
$$\frac{CLs^2}{\left(R_1+R_2\right)LCs^2+\left(R_1R_2C+L\right)s+R_1}$$